# How to group by opportunity owner Direct Vs. Indirect?

Tags: reporting

I need to report on our opptys, and group by our Direct Vs. Indirect ones.

- Each oppty is either owned by an employee or a partner.
- Each Account is either owned by an employee or a partner.

  Which field can I use in the report to do that grouping?

  - The `partner account` is either Null (for internal) or has a value of the partner - I thought to use it within a bucket, but I can't, and don't want to add to the report new partners in the future - needs to be dynamic.
- `owner role` same as with partner
- `profile` same - it can change in the future.
- All three fields do not comply, as they can be calculated on the account only, and the account itself does NOT have a `partner account`, only the Accont's Owner -> Account can have that.

  - I want to create some formula field (text, number, any) that will be based on the Account Partner Field. However, I can't locate it in the Field Formula values.

Any ideas?

[This link](https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?c=09a30000000D9y3&category=Data%20Import&p=4&qId=08730000000JLNi&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a30000000D9y3), describes `partneraccount` as a ready only (I know that)

Still, I am not able to access the read only field `PartnerAccount` from any formula field.

The other option will be a field update, and workflow, don't want to go that path, wanted a simple solution.

// UPDATE
I tried to use workflow rules and field updates. Added a checkbox: `Direct Sale` that is updated by the `PartnerAccount` Value:

[image]

That created an issue, as the rule is based on the Account Partner Account (which is true most of the time) - But I need to test that on the Oppty - Owner. - And that is NOT available in the Criteria.

- so I am at square one.

Comment: can you create bucket fields based on formulas? if so, try to create formula that indicates wether the opps is direct or indirect

Answer (score 2):

You could still do bucket fields for grouping. Since all of your internal accounts are null, use a Groupby filter where the value for Partner Account != null. That would group all of your partner accounts dynamically, including any new ones that are added later. All your internal accounts would have a value where the Partner Account = null.

Comment: I didn't know I can use a formula on the bucket filter.

Comment: Null is NOT a value I can select in the bucket.

Comment: You don't have to select null, it'll end up as "Other". Just bucket the real partners. But I think report bucket can have up to 20 entries which might be not nearly enough...

Comment: I still don't want to use a static convention, as in the future, adding new partners, will cause to edit each report.

Comment: If it won't allow you to enter null, will it allow you to enter `""` where there are no spaces between the quotes?? Perhaps that might produce the same results. Note: haven't tested, just a quick suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The not so nice solution was - A bucket field.

I created a bucket on the `Owner Alias` field, and entered all aliases of our Non Direct distributors.

The draw back, is that each time I will have a new distributor, I will need to manually add him to this report. - This is solved by having a preventive report (I have a dashboard full of those) that is selecting all aliases of partner type, which are NOT in the bucket field. IF an alias is found, than I need to update the Bucket, and the report.